# Linking to An Uploaded File in Django with Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, sorl-thumbnail, django-storage

I am using django-storages backend and I have previously not used Amazon S3. I have migrated to Amazon S3 by uploading the files via Firefox's S3 Manager.

THe problem is, with this code:

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ g.photo }}" class="lightbox" title="{{ g.description }}">
    {%  thumbnail g.photo '95x95' crop="center" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" />
    {% endthumbnail %}
</a>
```

The request generated does not include the required params in the GET request, like the Signature. However, the sorl-generated thumbnails work!

Is there something I'm missing with regards to uploading my files in S3? Is there additional code to be added in the href? Why is sorl able to retrieve the files and create a thumbnail out of it?

Comment: Some information is missing: Are the files in your S3 bucket private? If not, you don't need a signature. What is your MEDIA_URL set to?

Comment: I don't think they are. Because they are being displayed correctly by sorl. But the link to the original image (unresized) does not work.

Comment: Well, can you show your MEDIA_URL setting? And please show what {{ im.url }} displays in your html code.

Comment: im.url (img src attr) = http://s3.amazonaws.com:80/dragonflysco/cache%2F02%2Fda%2F02da8c3797d20e8562d475f7ceca3997.jpg

MEDIA_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

Comment: Seems like your "g.photo" does not contain the correct filename. What is the output for <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ g.photo }}"> ?

Comment: files are stored in the database as <dir>/image, the output of that anchor is the path to the image without signature, etc. The response sends back an xml with: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{e536a357-1173-a74d-a853-f42e34623a36} Line Number 1, Column 1: with a 403 response. the image exists, I checked it.

Comment: There must be an issue with the path to the original file. If you don't post it, I can't check it. Have you checked the request/response headers on retrieving the image?

Comment: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dragonflysco/item/79_20071206203815u.10.05.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is not accessible publicly. This may have happened on uploading or due bucket restrictions.

You could either change the ACL settings in S3 Manager for this file to public access (if only this file should be publicly readable), or create a Bucket policy for fine-grained permissions on the bucket - you can do that in the AWS Console.

If any file in the bucket shall be public, you should change the default ACL setting in your S3 client accordingly.

Comment: thanks! I just had to make the files or the directory they are in public!